# prediction on test set for Gaussian Process Regression in R

Tags: r, gaussian

The `mlegp` package explains how to do Gaussian Process fitting but the R code mentioned in the `mlegp` package only demonstrates the use of the `predict` method to reconstruct the original functional output. Can someone help me understand how to `predict` using GPR on a test set?

Answer (score 0):

The function `predict.gp` (which gets called when you use `predict` on an `mlpeg` object) takes a `newData` argument, see `?predict.gp`:

```
Usage:

     ## S3 method for class 'gp'
     predict(object, newData = object$X, se.fit = FALSE, ...)

Arguments:

  object: an object of class ‘gp’

 newData: an optional data frame or matrix with rows corresponding to
          inputs for which to predict.  If omitted, the design matrix
          ‘X’ of ‘object’ is used.
  ...
```

Consider the simple model

```
library(mlepg)
x = -5:5
y = sin(x) + rnorm(length(x),sd = 0.1)
fit = mlegp(x, y)
```

Then

```
predict(fit)
```

and

```
predict(fit, newData = fit$X)
```

gives the same result. You can then change `newData` according to your test data.

Comment: The predict function throws the error-no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "gp.list"

Comment: @aanchalsharma Please edit your main post to include representative & minimal sample data. It is very difficult (impossible) to help without knowing anything about (1) the data you're working with, and (2) the actual code you've been executing. To make your question reproducible, we should be able to copy&paste code from your post and reproduce the exact error you're seeing. Otherwise this is a guessing game. You should also take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).